# Bundle in Symfony2 to import contact from Yahoo and Gmail

Tags: symfony, import, gmail, yahoo

I would like to know there is an existing bundle or vendors in Symfony2 to import contact from Yahoo and Gmail.
I searched but find nothing. I also start to do it myself but i encountered some problems...

Comment: What were your problems?

Comment: finally i create a service to import contact from gmail but i don't know how to do the same for Yahoo. and the api doesn't help me because i work on localhost and the Yahoo api doesn't work with it...

Comment: Consider wrapping it up as a bundle and putting it up on GitHub. I'm sure a number of people (including me) would be interested in contributing.

Comment: Hey Nurikabe ! Sure i'll put it on Github but i would first like to finish with Yahoo. The doc and the api doesn't help me much... If anyone got a script to import contact from yahoo in php (not specially with symfony2) or other languages i'm interested !

Comment: I finally resolved my problem and create a service to import contact from gmail and yahoo ! I will post as soon as possible when i'll finish some test and implement on real project ! :)

Comment: Instead of creating from scratch, is it possible to bundle OpenInviter (openinviter.com) as Symfony2 Bundle? or maybe such bundle already exist?